# Can we write AngularJS code in prototype method or not?

Tags: prototype

I wrote the Angularjs code in Javascript prototype method. But I got confused if it is a good practice to write angularjs code in prototype. See the test example of my angularJS code below:

**APP File**

```
function myAppModule() {
    this.app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource']);
    this.controllers = {};
    this.RootScopes();
    this.Services();
    this.Directives();
    this.AppControllers();
}

myAppModule.prototype.RootScopes = function () {
    this.app.run(['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
        $rootScope.messageType = {
            success: 0
            , error: 1
        };

        $rootScope.requestType = {
            EDIT: 0
            , DELETE: 1
            , VIEW: 2
        };
    }]);
}

myAppModule.prototype.Services = function () {
    this.app.service('myAppService', ['$resource', '$rootScope', function ($resource, $rootScope) {
        //GET ALL DATA        

        this.save = function (data, callback, error) {
            var res = $resource('/testData/save', {}, {
                'save': {
                    method: 'POST'
                }
            });

            return res.save(data, callback, error);
        };

        this.get = function (id, clientId, callback, error) {
            var res = $resource('/testData/getdata', { id: '@id' }, {
                'get': {
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: {
                        'clientId': clientId
                    }
                }
            });

            return res.get({ Id: id }, callback, error);
        };

    }]);
}

myAppModule.prototype.Directives = function () {
    //Directive to attach popover on admin delete button
    this.app.directive('testDirective', ['$rootScope', '$timeout', '$compile', function ($rootScope, $timeout, $compile) {
        return {
            scope: {
                rowIndex: "@"
                , userAdminData: "="
            }
            , restrict: 'A'
            , replace: false
            , templateUrl: '../mytemplate/test.html'
            , link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
                scop.test_message = "Hello world!";
            }
        }
    }]);
}

myAppModule.prototype.AppControllers = function () {
    this.controllers.myController = new myController(this.app);
}
```

**My Controller**

```
function myController(appObj) {
    this.app = appObj;
    this.$scope = null; //$SCOPE
    this.$rootScope = null; //$RootSCOPE
    this.$timeout = null;
    this.$resource = null;
    this.$compile = null;
    this.adminService = null;
    this.Init();
}

myController.prototype.Init = function () {
    var _this = this;
    this.app.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$timeout', 'myAppService', function ($scope, $rootScope, $timeout, myAppService) {
        _this.$scope = $scope;
        _this.$rootScope = $rootScope;
        _this.$timeout = $timeout;
        _this.$compile = $compile;

        _this.adminService = AdministratorService;
        _this.initScopeVariables();
        _this.initEventHandlers();
        _this.pageLoadEvents();
    }]);
}

myController.prototype.pageLoadEvents = function () {
    this.getUserAdminList();
    _this.$scope.testFunction2();
}

myController.prototype.getDataFromServer = function (callBackEvents) {
    var _this = this;

    this.adminService.query(0, 0, 1, function (data) {
        _this.$scope.lstData = data;
        _this.$scope.testFunction1();
    }, function (err) {
        alert('data error');
    });
}

//All scope elements will be declared here
myController.prototype.initScopeVariables = function () {    
    this.$scope.lstData = [];
    this.$scope.myFoo = "Hello Foo";
    this.$scope.myBar = "Hello Bar";
}

//All events declared here
myController.prototype.initEventHandlers = function () {
    var _this = this;

    this.$scope.testFunction1 = function () {
       alert('function 1')
    }

    this.$scope.testFunction2 = function () {
        alert('function 2')
    }

    this.$scope.testFunction3 = function () {
        alert('function 3')
    }
}
```

I thought if i write my code in this way, i can understand any method easily. So what you people think, this is good? if not then why we cannot write the AngularJS code in this way?....

Thanks